# In Rails, can I create a model/controller called "Route(s)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a site in Ruby on Rails that is very map oriented and I would like to have a `model/controller` called `Route/Routes`. I've already created it and so far it seems to be causing no real issue with the actual "route" system in Rails. I couldn't find anything in my searches for best practice and whether I should change the name to something other than route. I'm still relatively early into it and sooner vs later would be better if this needs to be changed.

Versions `ruby 2.2.3` and `rails 4.2.4`

Comment: I don't think it would cause an issue, as neither `Route` nor `Routes` are classes in a standard Rails installation currently. But perhaps a more descriptive name would be appropriate, like `MapRoute` or something else more specific.

Comment: Good call. I can live with that. Thanks.